# implementin filter for vector of custom struct in RUST

Tags: rust, vector, serialization, iterator, rust-cargo

i am new to rust, like started yesterday new, and i am creating a todo/calendar app to learn. i am the very initial stage of defining by structures and implementations. i am stuck at creating a function that filters the vector. But i am getting an error while using `filter()` and `collect()` . i am not sure what needs to be done tbh , i did go on to learn more about serialization but couldnt get far. I would appreciate some advice or explanation what is the issue coz i dont get it.

the error is

```
error[E0277]: a value of type `TodoList<'_>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `structs::Todoitem::Todoitem<'_>`
    --> src/structs/Todolist.rs:92:26
     |
92   |             .into_iter().collect()
     |                          ^^^^^^^ value of type `TodoList<'_>` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=structs::Todoitem::Todoitem<'_>>`
```

my implementations and structs are as follows.

```rust
pub struct TodoList<'a> {
    pub items: Vec<Todoitem<'a>>,
}

... //my implementation for filter is..
    fn helperFilterStatus(&mut self, target: Types::Status) -> TodoList<'a> {
        self.items
            .into_iter().filter(|x_item| x_item.status==target).collect()
    }
```

and lastly `todoitem`

```
pub struct Todoitem<'a> {
    pub id: u32,
    pub title: &'a str,
    ...
  }
```

i have not added my full implementation but i can share git link if required.

Comment: It's generally expected that the question will contain not the "full implementation", but the [mre]; could you share the full error, at least, with all the `note`s attached?

Answer (score 0):

Comment on reddit helped: https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/1bn27hy/implementing_filter_for_vector_of_custom_struct/

```rust
impl<'a>  FromIterator<Todoitem<'a>> for TodoList<'a>  {
    fn from_iter<T: IntoIterator<Item = Todoitem<'a>> >  (iter: T) -> Self {
        let mut c =  TodoList { items: Vec::new() };
        for i in iter {
            c.add_item(i)
        }
        c
    }
}
```

```
    fn helperFilterStatus(&mut self, target: Types::Status) ->TodoList<'a>{
         self.items
            .drain(..).filter(|x_item| x_item.status==target).collect()
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you want `.drain()`? Is it expected that filtering for status removes all of the items from the original list?